# Bypassing the Neutral Safety Switch? No start no crank issue!

Tags: ignition, starter

I have a 2000 Acura TL, and it had been having some no-start no-crank issues, usually, I would turn the key and nothing would happen (just one click), it might take a few tries but eventually it would start up. It also had intermittent issues with releasing the shifter from park, I would have to keep pressing the brake pedal many times before I would hear it click and release the shifter.

Also one other issue which I can only imagine is related: sometimes when in park, the shifter would make a clicking noise and vibrate slightly--pressing the brake pedal would eliminate the noise and clicking however!

Anyway, it seems like the NSS has gone bad (unless any of you have better ideas), and it's not starting AT ALL now.

Is there an actual way to bypass the NSS since it's just a safety feature, to get the car running so I can get it fixed or get to and from school for the time being?

Would bridging the ignition relay force the starter to crank and allow me to drive the car? That seems like the simplest solution.

Thank you all

Comment: auto or manual? what engine? you can try jumping power at the starter relay to see if the starter works.

Comment: Automatic, sorry should have included that. Do you mean doing what I suggested in my original post? Like using a paperclip to bridge the starter relay connection?

Comment: yes that would be the best place to check all the circuits as well.

Comment: Will do soon. but if that does work can we assume its the NSS, and will the car be drivable or would the steering wheel still be locked, etc. ?

Comment: the steering wheel lock is part of the ignition switch setup so as long as your key turns it's fine. If the engine turns over when you jump power to the starter solenoid then you have to look at the two other pins of the relay to determine where you're losing a signal. It could be the transmission range switch (nss) or it could be from the ignition switch.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a paper clip.  More like a screwdriver - hold the plastic handle.

Comment: short piece of insulated wire with the ends bared...